Does the Intensity of color in OpenCV image matter?
Here is a simple code which puts a text value onto a black frame and displays it:
frame = np.zeros((50,200,3))

org=(0,45)
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale=1
fontColor=(1,0,0)    ##rgb
out_img = cv2.putText(frame, "text" , org, font, fontScale, fontColor)

plt.imshow(out_img)

I am trying to understand how the color intensity is treated:

fontColor=(1,0,0) versus fontColor=(255,0,0). Both print red text with no change to intensity. Shouldn't the intensity vary based on the strength we have given? Same with other colors also. For e.g (0,1,0) versus fontColor=(0,255,0)
How do we explain behaviour when we are mixing colors. For e.g. by fontColor=(255,255,0), we are mixing red and green which rightly gives us yellow text. But fontColor=(1,255,0) also gives us exactly the same yellow text (as if red and green are mixed in equal proportions)

Sidenote: The problem I am trying to solve is to decipher the color of the text in a given image.  I was able to get the text contours and isolate the text by putting it onto a large black mask and then get the second prominent color (foreground). So far so good. However I am having trouble deciphering the intensities of the obtained foreground color.

You didn't specify a data type when creating frame, so by default it's a np.float64. Per the documentation, for floating point images Matplotlib's imshow assumes the intensities to lie in the range [0.0, 1.0]. Since 1.0 is the brightest possible, anything higher will be clipped to 1.0, so (1,0,0) and (255,0,0) will look exactly the same.

and (255,128,64) will be white.

ok. I see. Rather silly of me. I will still retain the question in case anyone else runs along the same path. By playing in the range 0-1, I am able to get the intensities & the color mixes I want. This is for matplotlib. It is possible that other libraries (say opencv) could behave differently and I guess the only solution is to explore the behaviour of each individual library and plan accordingly.

inside plt.imshow() use the arguments vmin and vmax to tweek the intensities.
